# 2D Plotting from lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Is it possible to do a 2D plot taking the point coordinates from separate lists of x and y values? These lists were produced by calculations within the same notebook. For a small number of points it is easy to enter x & y values by hand but it gets tedious as the number of points grows (I've done it.). If this is possible, I cannot find it in the documentation. Presently, I have over 40 points to plot and I expect the lists to grow. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Transpose[{xlist, ylist}]` to make the list of points, then use `ListPlot`.

Comment: Welcome BillT, Don't forget to vote up and accept any answers that you approve of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's generate some data:

```
data1 = Table[i, {i, 0, 1000}];
data2 = Table[Sin[t]^2 - Cos[t^2] 5 Sin[t], {t, 0, 1000}];
```

Combine them in a couple ways...

```
newdata = Transpose[{data1, data2}];
newdata2 = Table[{data1[[i]], data2[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[data1]}];

newdata === newdata2
(*True*)
```

Have a look at Every 10th element in the list to see if it looks correct.

```
Take[newdata, {1, -1, 100}]

   {{1, -5 Cos[1] Sin[1] + 
   Sin[1]^2}, {101, -5 Cos[10201] Sin[101] + 
   Sin[101]^2}, {201, -5 Cos[40401] Sin[201] + 
   Sin[201]^2}, {301, -5 Cos[90601] Sin[301] + 
   Sin[301]^2}, {401, -5 Cos[160801] Sin[401] + 
   Sin[401]^2}, {501, -5 Cos[251001] Sin[501] + 
   Sin[501]^2}, {601, -5 Cos[361201] Sin[601] + 
   Sin[601]^2}, {701, -5 Cos[491401] Sin[701] + 
   Sin[701]^2}, {801, -5 Cos[641601] Sin[801] + 
   Sin[801]^2}, {901, -5 Cos[811801] Sin[901] + Sin[901]^2}}
```

Use `ListLinePlot` or `ListPlot` to Plot such data,

```
ListLinePlot[Take[newdata, {1, -1, 50}], ImageSize -> Large, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", Frame -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

[image]

Table and Transpose are your friends Read in the documentation for [List manipulations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list with `x` values, and another with `y` values, like this:

```
x= {1,2,3,4,5};

y={2,4,6,8,10};
```

Then you can plot them simply as:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Check the documentation of [ListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) to get a better idea of the basic plotting capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Example list:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
y = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
ListPlot[Thread[{x, y}], Joined -> True]
```

This will create a joined plot of all the data avilable in list 'x' and liat 'y'.